# Ember view is not updating after re-ordering array used to create child views

Tags: arrays, sorting, ember.js

I have an activities view that contains an array of activities. This array gets sorted sometimes based on a calculated property(distanced_from_home) that the user can update. When the array is sorted I want the child views to be re-rendered by according to the new order. Here is my Template and View:

*index.html*

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="activities">
    <h1>Activities</h1>
    {{#each activities}}
      {{view App.ActivityView activityBinding="this"}}
    {{/each}}
  </script>
```

*app.js*

```
  App.ActivitiesView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'activities',
    activities: (function() {
      var list;
      list = App.activityController.activities;
      console.log("Activities View");
      console.log(list);
      return list;
    }).property('App.activityController.activities', 'App.activityController.activities.@each.distance_to_home').cacheable()
  });
```

When I cause the distance_to_home property to change, the console.log output shows the list array is properly sorted, but the children views are not re-rendered in the new order. If I leave this view and then comeback to it (it is rendered again) then the correct order is shown.

What should I do to get the view to update automatically?

Thanks,

### *EDIT*

This seems to be working [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962839/sorting-a-list-in-emberjs-and-having-that-reflect-in-the-view) and my 'activities' computed function is definitely firing, but no re-ordering of the view...  I also tried to use an observer, but the results are the same.

```
  App.ActivitiesView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'activities',
    classNames: ['activities rounded shadow'],
    homeBinding: 'App.user.home',
    activities: [],
    homeChanged: (function() {
      console.log("homeChanged()");
      this.set('activities', App.activityController.activities.sort(this.compare_activities));
      return null;
    }).observes('home'),

    compare_activities: function(a, b) {
      var result;
      result = 0;
      if (App.user.home != null) {
        result = a.get('distance_to_home') - b.get('distance_to_home');
      }
      return result;
    },

  });
```

I also tried to set the 'activities' parameter to an empty array and then reset it to the ordered array to force it to re-render, but this has no effect.

```
  App.ActivitiesView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'activities',
    classNames: ['activities rounded shadow'],
    homeBinding: 'App.user.home',
    activities: [],
    homeChanged: (function() {
      console.log("homeChanged()");
      this.set('activities', []);
      this.set('activities', App.activityController.activities.sort(this.compare_activities));
      return null;
    }).observes('home'),

    compare_activities: function(a, b) {
      var result;
      result = 0;
      if (App.user.home != null) {
        result = a.get('distance_to_home') - b.get('distance_to_home');
      }
      return result;
    },

  });
```

### *EDIT (the second)*

So it seems that using Ember.copy finally solved this.  Setting the array property to an empty array (or null) did not have any effect. Here's the View code that finally worked:

```
  App.ActivitiesView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'activities',
    classNames: ['activities rounded shadow'],
    homeBinding: 'App.user.home',
    activities: [],
    homeChanged: (function() {
      var list;
      list = App.activityController.activities.sort(this.compare_activities);
      this.set('activities', Ember.copy(list), true);
      return null;
    }).observes('home'),
    compare_activities: function(a, b) {
      var result;
      result = 0;
      if (App.user.home != null) {
        result = a.get('distance_to_home') - b.get('distance_to_home');
      }
      return result;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle with sample data? I think the `Ember.copy` is not the best solution. Also have a look at recently introduced `arrangedContent` [https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/84e9626522a686c29e6d6f2127d35c2dc9698d80/packages/ember-runtime/lib/system/array_proxy.js#L59-66]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does this help?  http://jsfiddle.net/rNzcy/

Putting together this simple example, I was a little confused why the view update didn't "just work" when sorting the content array in the ArrayController. It seems there are 2 simple things you can do to trigger the view update. Either:

- Set the content array to null, sort the original content, and then set the sorted content.

or

- Clone the content array when sorting it, via Ember.copy()

I guess Ember detects when a completely new Array object is set, and that triggers all the expected binding/view updates. Otherwise, maybe it's doing some sort of caching and if the Array object does not change (i.e. it's sorted in place) then no bindings fire? Just guessing.

UPDATE:
See discussion @ https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/575#issuecomment-4397658 which has an improved workaround using propertyWillChange() and propertyDidChange() (http://jsfiddle.net/rNzcy/4/) -- should be a lot more efficient then cloning a large array.

Comment: I noticed that you used an Array controller.  My controller is a standard Ember Object.  I will try what you posted soon and get back.

Comment: Adam,  It was 'Ember.copy()' that did the trick. Thanks again for your time and effort (sample code was really helpfull)

Comment: Cool, glad that helped you.

Note, I was using ArrayController because it is "bindings aware", see http://ember-docs.herokuapp.com/#doc=Ember.ArrayController&src=false

But that's why I'm surprised we had to use Ember.copy() (or the other workaround I mentioned). I might be a bug in Ember? I'm going to share the example on github and see what the devs say.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same issue. And I don't think observe `array.@each` or `array.length` is good practice. At last I found this http://jsfiddle.net/rNzcy/4/ i.e. call `this.propertyDidChange('foo')`